# Problema compilar Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget

Estoy iniciando con Xamarin,pero estoy viendo muchos problemas para compilar un proyecto PCL aún siguiendo tutoriales parece ser que las **dll** y/o paquetes **nuget** cambian constantemente, lo cual resulta demasiado tedioso estar refactorizando código y reemplazando paquetes que ya funcionaban, en especial cuando son desarrollos grandes, éste problema resulta una baja productividad del desarrollo.

Tengo VisualStudio 2017 Community y al actualizar el Xamarin.Forms(desde 2.3.4.247 a version 3.6.0.709) me manda el siguiente
error:

> Descripción   Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido Error      MSB6006:
>   "java.exe" salió con el código 1.`.

Mi pregunta concreta:

¿es posible conservar las versiones originales con las que el proyecto fué creado sin tener que cambiar sintaxis de código en uno o dos años?

Comment: Hola, es raro que un proyecto nuevo que creaste comience con una version tan vieja de Xamarin.Forms, y si es posible que las mantengas pero se actualiza constantemente para mejoras y herramientas, seria un desperdicio no aprovecharlas. De todos modos ese error es el unico que no te deja compilar o levantar la app en el emulador?

Comment: Gracias por responder, cada quien tiene una percepción sobre a partir de cuantos años es obsoleto,hay empresas q siguen trabajando en cobol desde 2000,webforms hasta estos días(la ver. de Xamarin utilicé esa xq de momento fué videotuto que explicaba mejor y permitía trabajar con la herramienta que tenía en este momento), pero aquí el punto era la consolidación de paquetes nuget,el otro error es una advertencia de que servicio de aceleración por hardware no está disponible y a pesar de agregar directiva en el Manifest parece no funcionar,desconosco que componentes debieran estar en VS Comunity